# What mimeCodec in mediasouce is compatible with ie and Firefox

Tags: media-source

My audio stream needs to start with audio/mpeg, so how do I write my mimeCodec?
I tried'audio/mpeg; codecs' but it doesn't work on Firefox and ie

Comment: Is not a random string. It needs to match the contents of the stream/file. What is the codec of the media you want to play?

Comment: @szatmary I want to play an audio stream, which is of audio/mpeg type. I tried mimeCodec which is'audio/mpeg; codecs'. Chrome supports this mimeCodec, but IE and Firefox do not. I want to find one that can be supported on IE and firefox mimeCodec, can you help me?

Comment: This is an example of our audio: https://node1.me.deepsound.cn/9ed1a381_baf5beb2d99189a988c0b805e5c838c177021c5ae706b56c.mp3

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34498784/362536