# Cannot replay MP3 in Firefox using MediaSource even though it works in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, media-source

I have implemented a simple audio player in my web application and noticed that it is not working in Firefox (let me just ... ).

What I get is an error:

```
ERROR DOMException: MediaSource.addSourceBuffer: Type not supported in MediaSource
```

This is followed by a warning:

```
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: audio/mpeg
```

This is the implementation for the `sourceopen` event handler:

```js
private onSourceOpen = (e) => {
  this.logger.debug('onSourceOpen');

  if (!this.sourceBuffer) {
    this.sourceBuffer = this.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('audio/mpeg');
  }

  this.mediaSource.removeEventListener('sourceopen', this.onSourceOpen);
  this.fetchRange(this.trackPlayUrl, 0, this.segmentLength, (chunk) => this.appendSegment(chunk));
}
```

Where

```js
// Create the media source object
this.mediaSource = new MediaSource();
this.mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', this.onSourceOpen);
```

Why does it hate me?

Comment: It's not just you.  MediaSource hates everyone.  :-)  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34498784/362536

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the link. Guess I have to use a different format then .. Also glad I'm not alone here .. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you try to create a SourceBuffer, you should always call `MediaSource.isTypeSupported` to determine whether it is likely to play. If that returns false, the user agent is telling you it definitely won't work.

On the latest Firefox:

```
>> MediaSource.isTypeSupported('audio/mpeg')
<- false
```

It hates you because Firefox's MediaSource implementation can't play content with that MIME type, whereas Chrome's can.

AAC in ISOBMFF has very broad support, though this would require transcoding and repackaging your audio - try:

```
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"')
```

Comment: So, that means that mp3 is not the format I can use here? Is there an overview somewhere where I can see what mime-types are supported by what browsers in general? I just can't find anything ..

Comment: AAC in an ISOBMFF container has broad support, but you'd have to transcode and repackage your media. String for `isTypeSupported` would be  `'audio/mp4, codecs="mp4a.40.2"'` for AAC-LC.

Comment: I've just tried that but Chrome does not support `audio/mp4` it would seem.. I get `false` for `audio/mp4` and `audio/mp4, codecs="mp4a.40.2"`. Only `audio/mpeg` returns `true`  asking `isTypeSupported`.

Comment: Apologies - it's my error. That comma should be a `;`, giving `'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"'`, which definitely returns `true` for me. Will edit original answer.

Comment: Ineed, that's giving `true` now. I have also tried just putting `aucio/aac` which does not seem to make a difference for playing the audio though.

Comment: This $h!7 is still not working ^^ I now convert my audios to AAC format using ffmpeg, and yes, `isTypeSupported` returns `true` but the MediaSource says: `MediaSource.addSourceBuffer: Type not supported in MediaSource` .. it only works on chrome but not on Firefox ..

Comment: I created a new question for this. I guess I need to be more specific with ffmpeg .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412488/convert-audio-to-audio-mp4-codecs-mp4a-40-2